# Detecting 1'bx and 1'bz bits in a Verilog variable

Tags: verilog

I have a 128 bit wire:

```
wire [127:0] test;
```

I want to stop simulation if any of the bits of `test` is `1'bx` or `1'bz`. This is what I tried:

```
if(&test == 1'bx || &test == 1'bz) begin
   $stop;
end
```

Unfortunately, `1'bx` and `1'bz` do not seem to propagate under `&`. I have also tried replacing `&test` with `|test`.

How can I quickly check if `test` contains any "don't care" or "tristate" bits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit-wise xor. Any `x` or `z` in the packed array that is xor will result in `1'bx`.

```
if ( ^test === 1'bx ) begin
    $stop;
end
```

Comment: I think you need to use `===` in the comparison instead of `==`.

Comment: @ThePhoton , Thanks, for a moment I thought "case equality" (`===`) was something added in IEEE std 1800. It is in part of IEEE std 1364-1995, first shown in section 4.1, table 4-1.